# Vuejs, Plugin, global method/property not found

Tags: plugins, vue.js

What am I doing wrong here?  I install a plugin, and set a global property, but then in my method's I can't access that property.

main.js for my root Vue component

```
import Vue from 'vue'
...
Vue.use({
  install (Vue) {
    let googleAuth = null
    console.log('called!')
    Vue.auth = {
      setAuth (auth) {
        googleAuth = auth
      },
      isAuthenticated () {
        return googleAuth !== null && googleAuth.isSignedIn.get()
      },
      currentUser () {
        return googleAuth.currentUser.get()
      },
      currentUserProfile () {
        return this.currentUser().getBasicProfile()
      },
      getIdToken () {
        return this.currentUser().getAuthResponse().id_token
      }
    }
  }
})
```

App.vue from root Vue component

```
<template></template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Trudit',
    data () {
      return {
        title: 'Trudit'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSignInSuccess (googleUser) {
        console.log(this)
        this.auth.setAuth(googleUser)   //<-  this.auth === undefined
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAuth' of undefined
>       at VueComponent.onSignInSuccess (eval at 57 (0.83049e6….hot-update.js:13), :17:16)
>       at boundFn (eval at  (app.js:630), :126:14)
>       at H_. (cb=gapi.loaded_0:285)
>       at cb=gapi.loaded_0:175
>       at h.r2 (cb=gapi.loaded_0:78)
>       at xs (cb=gapi.loaded_0:81)
>       at Wq (cb=gapi.loaded_0:81)
>       at _.C.uea (cb=gapi.loaded_0:80)
>       at Ap (cb=gapi.loaded_0:74)

Comment: I guess you should do `Vue.prototype.auth = someObj` so that newly created components can inherit them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Srinivas Damam pointed out I needed to set it using prototype.

`Vue.prototype.auth` fixed it